# What C++ book talks about recommended ways of organizing big projects?

Tags: c++, coding-style

I would like to know about books that talk about design issues like when to use namespaces and other coding standards to write good quality efficient C++ code. One that talks about Code testing will also be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

["Large-Scale C++ Software Design" by John Lakos](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620) worked great for me years ago on how to organise code in large projects.

On testing, this is not my area, and I cannot recommend a great book. What I can do is discourage you from getting ["Testing Computer Software", 2nd edition by Cem Kaner, Jack Falk and Hung Q. Nguyen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471358460). I found it severely dated and extremely clumsy. But please take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: +1 was about to recommend exactly the same book.

Answer (score 1):

For big projects, it is essential to follow a common design and coding style. Consistently.

I found the following book useful to have a common ground in a big project.

[C++ Coding Standards: 101 Rules, Guidelines, and Best Practices by Andrei Alexandrescu, Herb Sutter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321113586)

Answer (score 0):

book about refactoring: [http://www.amazon.com/Refactoring-Improving-Design-Existing-Code/dp/0201485672](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672)